# Terraform "AuthorizationFailed" with Azure provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm an owner of an Azure resource group but not have permissions on the subscription or on the management group. 
When configuring the "azurerm" provider inside my .tf file, I've added subscription id and tenant id (I'm not the owner of that subscription).

--------------------- UPDATE ---------------------

I'm trying to apply Linux virtual machine using Terraform but having authorization issues while planning the .tf file.
[image]

I've listed all my accounts using Azure CLI (want to connect the second subscription in the output below):
[image]

I've succeeded authenticating to the subscription using Azure CLI with the command (it worked):

```
az account set --subscription="SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
```

It's my default and current subscription:
[image]

Also, I was able to create and manage resources inside my resource group in that subscription using Azure CLI.
However, I added the exact tenant ID and the exact subscription ID inside my .tf file and still got the same credentials errors during the "terraform plan".
[image]

Using Azure CLI or Azure portal I am able to create and manage resources inside the resource group's scope, although using terraform I'm facing problems.

Thank you :)

Comment: Make sure you logged in to the right subscription : `az login --subscription %Subscription_ID%`

Answer (score 0):

According to your story, you just set the tenant id and subscription id in the azure provider, so it seems you [authenticate via Azure CLI](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/azure_cli.html). No matter you have a user account or a service principal, the owner role of the resource group is enough to create virtual machine in the resource  group. In this way, you need to logging into the Azure CLI first. As it shows in the link I have provided.

Comment: I've followed the link and authenticated to the subscription using Azure CLI (worked). After that, I added the tenant ID and the subscription ID inside my .tf file and still got credentials errors during "terraform plan".

I've updated the question I've open.

Comment: @YuvalPodoksik The subscription id you set in the Terraform `azurerm` provider should the same as you logging with CLI. You can use the CLI command `az account show` to see what is the right subscription id.

Comment: Of course, I understand that. The subscription ID and the tenant ID inside terraform match to those listed in Azure CLI.

Comment: @YuvalPodoksik Are you sure it's the same one that you have the permission?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm sure, updated the question again.

Comment: @YuvalPodoksik Do you create the virtual machine in the resource group that you have the owner role?

Comment: Yes, I have owner role assignment on the resource group's scope so I'm the owner of the rg, vnet, subnet, and more inside. All these parameters match the names of the resources I'm the owner of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213908/discussion-between-charles-xu-and-yuval-podoksik).

Comment: @YuvalPodoksik Do you still work on this problem? I didn't see any updates.